# jQuery - div not closing when screen is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code that will display the Hello-World div when the search-icon is clicked. I want this to only happen when the `screen size is < 768px`.

The problem I am facing is the fact that the div does not hide when the `screen is > 768px`, ***if the div is first opened*** in `screen size < 768px`, and not closed before the screen is resized.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showsearch').click(function() {
    $('.input-display').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Se my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkgexf0u/), open the div, not close, and resize the screen!

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using JavaScript to show/hide div, You'll have to use `!important` in css to override inline styles (`display: block;`) added by JavaScript. Try this:

```
.input-visible {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you :D